# Assert some key/value pairs in a Hash

Tags: rspec, puppet

I have a define, that accepts a hash:

```
Hash[String, Variant[String,Integer,Undef]] $property_additions;
```

I can test this property with the following rspec

```
    it { is_expected.to contain_my__define('instance-name').with_property_additions({
      'my_first_property' => 'my_first_value',
      'my_second_property' => 'my_second_value',
      ...,
      ...,
    })}
```

This tests, that the hash contains listed values and only listed values. In order to use it, I need to list here all key/value pairs from the Hash.

**My question is**, how can I assert, that some properties are set without specifying all the properties from the hash?

Put it simple, I'm looking for some rspec matcher, like "with_key_value_pairs_included({...})".

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your test setup, but to assert some value includes a key value pair, you can use the standard `includes` matcher and pass it a hash:

```
expect(subject.attr).to include(:foo => "bar")
```

Comment: That's good general information, but not relevant in the context of this particular question.

Comment: Yes, in my understanding, there is no way I can get hold of this hash instance, so I can pass it to the `expect(..)`...

Answer (score 1):

I take it that the entity under test is a class that you expect to declare `My::Define[instance-name]`, as opposed to the `My::Define` defined type itself.  If it were the latter then it would be pointless to allow for the parameter value to be in any way different from the one you previously specified.

> **My question is**, how can I assert, that some properties are set without specifying all the properties from the hash?

If I understand the question correctly then this is a reasonable thing to want to do, but
rspec-puppet does not make provisions for it.  I can't altogether rule out the possibility that you could pass an argument of some custom `Hash` subclass that somehow makes [rspec-puppet's parameter check](https://github.com/rodjek/rspec-puppet/blob/b8b141248482073f1e70f1d7ffa85e0b1396c776/lib/rspec-puppet/matchers/parameter_matcher.rb#L86-L101), work out as you have in mind, but even if you managed to make that work, it would be complicated and brittle.